# Validate Object while deserialization by using Custom ObjectMapper in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, microservices

I have a class called `Student`. I want to validate the object. I have used few annotation in model class along with I have written custom validation logic. Still it is not working. But when I remove all the annotation from model class it is working properly.

Model class is

```java
@Value
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Jacksonized
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Student {
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    
    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty(required = true)
    private Address address;
}
@Value
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Jacksonized
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Address {
    @NotNull
    private String addrName;
}
```

Then after that I have created a factory class which create custom objectMapper.

```java
@Configuration
class ObjectMapperFactory {

    @Bean
    public static ObjectMapper getObjectMapperWithValidation() {
        SimpleModule validationModule = new SimpleModule();
        validationModule.setDeserializerModifier(new BeanDeserializerModifierWithValidation());
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(validationModule);
        return mapper;
    }
}


class BeanDeserializerModifierWithValidation extends BeanDeserializerModifier {

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> modifyDeserializer(DeserializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer) {
        System.out.println(deserializer instanceof BeanDeserializer);
        System.out.println(beanDesc.getBeanClass().getName());
        if (deserializer instanceof BeanDeserializer) {
            System.out.println("it is instance of");
            return new BeanDeserializerWithValidation((BeanDeserializerBase) deserializer);
        }
        return deserializer;
    }
}

class BeanDeserializerWithValidation extends BeanDeserializer {

    protected BeanDeserializerWithValidation(BeanDeserializerBase src) {
        super(src);
    }

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("inside deserialize method>>>>>>>>>");
        Object instance = super.deserialize(p, ctxt);
        ValidationUtil.validate(instance);
        return instance;
    }
}

class ValidationUtil {

    private static final ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    private static final Validator validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();

    public static <T> void validate(T obj) {
        Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> violations = validator.validate(obj);
        if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ConstraintViolationException(violations);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Test class which contain `main()`.

```java
public class StudentTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        StudentTest studentTest = new StudentTest();
        Student student1 = studentTest.readStudent();
    }

    Student readStudent() throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\ACNSMB\\project_stuff\\validStudent.json");
        ObjectMapper mapper = ObjectMapperFactory.getObjectMapperWithValidation();
        return mapper.readValue(inputStream, Student.class);
    }
```

here if the `addrName` is null it should throws `ConstraintViolationException`. But it is not throwing even `addrName` is null.

But when i am removing all the annotation from model class and I kept only `@Data` it is working fine.
But I need all the annotation along with my custom ObjectMapper validation.
I tried `@JsonProperty(required = true)` in field level also still it is not working

Could anyone please help me on this.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: what do you get when student.name is null ?
"@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)" seem to be the issue here.

why it works with "@Data" is because "@Data" adds "@RequiredArgsConstructor" and also checks for null

Comment: It was my mistake i am not using this annotation @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL). Actually i am not getting any Exception but even addrName is null or address is null Deserialization is successful but it should give ConstraintViolationException.